# Не видит константу как исправить?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Почему при добавление в массив значение под элемента  - logKeyForView, а не его значение? Как это исправить.
Получается что он не видит эту константу.

```
 const logKeyForView  = "#VIEW1";

module.exports = async function (req, cs, cb) {

  function formatArray(array,end,result){
        for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            result.push({logKeyForView:{
                'object':array[i].object,'result':[],.....

            }});

        }
    }
}
```

т.е. ответ

```
logKeyForView: {

    object: 'S0',

    result: [],

  }
```

А должно быть :

```
 #VIEW1: {

        object: 'S0',

        result: [],

      }
```

Comment: result.push({ `${logKeyForView}`:{
Так можно попробовать, в обратных ковычках

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо создать объект, установить ему свойство, а потом добавить в массив

```
const obj = {};

obj[logKeyForView] = {};

result.push(obj);
```

---

Можно "обвернуть" переменную в квадратные скобки, но это будет работать только с ES6

```
result.push({[logKeyForView]:{}});
```